# Size of classical liver lobule across species

Tags: human-anatomy, literature, histology, liver

A classical liver lobule is made up of a central vein and the portal triads.  A typical human liver weighs around 3 lbs. , while a typical bovine liver weighs around 12 lbs.  I was wondering if anyone had a reference that might discuss the size of a bovine liver lobule vs. the size of a human liver lobule.  Specifically, is the bovine liver lobule also larger than a human liver lobule?